# export hierarchical radgrid to excel get crashed for large records

Tags: c#, telerik, radgrid

I have implemented export hierarchical radgrid to excel but show crashed when large data is there.The content size becomes very large and telerik do not recommend or handle large data.How to solve this to overcome performance issue

Comment: Kendo Support forum says... You can upgrade to Excel 2007 which supports more than *65K* records to be exported to excel. How many records you are trying to Export???

Comment: above 10,000 records

Comment: hi, we are already using excel 2007.can we have third party tool to export nested grid to excel

Comment: 10,000 records with Nested rows definitely will give you performance hit.  Since you know how many looping will go through each records and nested rows. The UI will hang obviously. To overcome this you have to have the load set of records some thing like "**Load More**" 100 records for each click. I hope you are using Ajax calls and You just need to pass `rowindex` to load each 100 records.

Comment: can we have some another solution because my functionality is to export current displaying  data in excel based on user set pagesize of grid it can be 10,000 or less or can be more

Comment: If that is your case you have to take care of your code performance. Reduce the looping statements (Use LinQ / Lambda), reduce unused variable declarations & parameters and  Use `Async` programming (load / loop it might reduce some performance hit). You know we can't provide the solution from word of mouth. :( Clear the unused memory objects. See some best practices in JS as well.

Comment: Post some code here so that i can take look / just contact me through skype `rajeshkumar_speaks` we can discuss better. Best of LUCK. :)